# Centring Flexbox newsletter submit icon

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my code snippet for newsletter submit form , I just want to keep vertically center icon, which is little bit displace from its center position. So finally I want to keep icon fluid center.

```css
.cm-subscription {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .cm-subscription {
    max-width: 340px;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

.cm-subscription form {
  font-family: Arial;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.cm-subscription form button {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  /*gradient*/
  background: green;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cm-subscription form button:hover {
  background: #004d00;
}

.cm-subscription form button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.cm-flex {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.cm-subscription form input {
  padding: 7px 18px;
  height: 43px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #a2aebb;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  border-right: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.cm-subscription form input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!--Footer Newsletter Subscription-->
<div class="cm-subscription">
  <form autocomplete="off" action="/subscribe" method="post">
    <div class="cm-flex">
      <div style="flex: 1 1 0;">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john@example.com" required>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left: -20px;">
        <button type="submit">&#10230;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't understand. Can you explain clearly?

Comment: I don't see any misalignment in the output of your code. If you think the arrow is misaligned, you can put it in a span and add `display: inline-block` and then use `vertical-align` to move it up and down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that for the arrow you are using a unicode character [long rightwards arrow](https://graphemica.com/%E2%9F%B6). It is, by itself, not vertically centered in text line. Of course, you can try to work/cheat around that by adjusting paddings etc., but this is not a sustainable solution (as the paddings may need to be tweaked according to element height and font size). Instead, why not use an actual icon, e.g. [long-arrow-right](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/long-arrow-right) from [font awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/):

```
<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

An example of your form with just the arrow replaced can be found in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqMQvR)